# Cross-Browser list of available Hot-Keys

Tags: cross-browser, accessibility

I'm working on a Asp.Net MVC3 application and am adapting it for keyboard accessibility compliance.  I have the basic navigation working fine.

I'm going to be adding some shortcut keys.  My problem is that I don't know which hot-keys I can safely use for all the major browsers. IE, FF & Chrome in my case.  Is there a reference somewhere I can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm) I don't know if it's completely up to date but it appears to be a good reference for multiple browser keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You are right about being a little out of date, but it was exactly what I was looking for.